# jQuery bounce and ease not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to figure out why the jQuery drop down I created is not easing down and bouncing.. It seems to be adding and removing the classes as it should but the rest is not working.

Here is my jQuery:

```
var $$ = jQuery;
$$(document).ready(function() {
$$(".cartTop").hover(function() {
$$(".quickcart a.product-image img").addClass("dropcartimg");
$$(".quickcart").addClass("cart-active");
$$(".cartTop .quickcart").stop(true, true).delay(300).slideDown(500, "easeOutBounce");
        }, function() {
$$(".quickcart").removeClass("cart-active");
$$(".cartTop .quickcart").stop(true, true).delay(300).fadeOut(800, "easeInCubic");
        });
});
```

Here is all my code :)

http://jsfiddle.net/JkX4g/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include jQuery easing plugin to work:
http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/

Also you don't need to add/remove class as you're using `display: block;` which will break your jQuery animation. Tried with your JS Fiddle and it's working now for me.

Comment: I have the easing plugin included. Its also in my fiddle :)

Comment: Ahhhh that was it :) After removing the add and remove class feature that displays it as a block it works perfect!! So I am guessing that this function has display as a block built right in. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, jQuery handles that by default.

Answer (score 0):

The JS:

```
var $ = jQuery;
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".cartTop").hover(function() {
                        $(".quickcart a.product-image img").addClass("dropcartimg");
                        $(".quickcart").addClass("cart-active");
            $(".cartTop .quickcart").stop(false, false).delay(300).slideDown(500);
        }, function() {
$(".quickcart").removeClass("cart-active");
            $(".cartTop .quickcart").stop(true, true).delay(300).fadeOut(800);
        });
});
```

My [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/blackhawx/JkX4g/9/)

If you want to add easing, then you should include the easing plugin, as an external script, along with your javascript.

Comment: Thanks. I gave this a try and after trying it out it wants to work half the time and the other half either it doesn't work or will not open. This is in Firefox and I have not tried it in other browsers. Also, I had to define `jQuery` as `$$` b/c Magento using `prototype.js` Any ideas why it is acting up?

Comment: Try like this 
`jQuery(document).ready(function($){ /* Code Here with $ */ });`

Comment: Thanks for your help! It was actually the add/remove class that was breaking it :)

Comment: I know, that's just for your conflict problem :)